# Is there a general dilogarithm formula for the Cheeger–Chern–Simons class?

Tags: chern-simons-theory, group-cohomology, lie-groups, hyperbolic-geometry, polylogarithms

I'm looking for a generalization of the calculation of the hyperbolic volume and Chern–Simons invariant for $\operatorname{SL}(2,\mathbb C)$ representations in terms of the Rogers dilogarithm.

Recall that for a complex Lie group $G$, we have the Cheeger–Chern–Simons class $\hat c_2:H_3(G,\mathbb Z)\to\mathbb C/\mathbb Z$ (that's the group homology of $G$ in the discrete topology, with coefficients in $\mathbb Z$).  If $G=\operatorname{SL}(2,\mathbb C)$, there is a nice explicit formula for this map, which is important in the calculation of hyperbolic volume.  We'll now describe it briefly.

Recall that the pre-Bloch group $\mathcal P(\mathbb C)$ is the free abelian group on symbols $[z]$ for $z\in\mathbb C\setminus\{0,1\}$ modulo a certain "five-term relation".  There is a map $\mathcal P(\mathbb C)\to\bigwedge^2\mathbb C$ given by $[z]\mapsto z\wedge(1-z)$, and we define the Bloch group $\mathcal B(\mathbb C)$ to be the kernel of this map.  Then $\mathcal B(\mathbb C)$ is isomorphic to $H_3(\operatorname{SL}(2,\mathbb C),\mathbb Z)$ (ignoring small 2- or 3-torsion).  There is a natural map from $\mathcal P(\mathbb C)$ to $\mathbb C$ given by the Rogers dilogarithm function (which satisfies the same five-term relation), and this restricted to $\mathcal B(\mathbb C)$ is exactly the Cheeger–Chern–Simons class.  [I'm lying a bit here; actually we need to use the *extended* Bloch group due to Neumann.]  This description of $H_3(\operatorname{SL}(2,\mathbb C),\mathbb Z)$ is related to the Suslin complex for $\operatorname{SL}(2,\mathbb C)$ acting on $\mathbb P^1(\mathbb C)$.

Question: are there similar explicit formulas for $\hat c_2$ for other groups $G$?  At best, I'd like a formula which works for any semisimple $G$, including exceptional groups, but even just giving something that works for $G=\operatorname{SL}(n,\mathbb C)$ would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Garoufalidis, D. Thurston, and Zickert are working on a related question. 

http://www.math.columbia.edu/~walterfest/abstracts/Zickert.html

Comment: Any updates on this question?

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the [comments](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/70868/is-there-a-general-dilogarithm-formula-for-the-cheeger-chern-simons-class#comment179255_70868), [a paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1111.2828) [1] of Garoufalidis, D. Thurston, and Zickert answers this question for $\operatorname{SL}_n(\mathbb{C})$.

[1]
*Garoufalidis, Stavros; Thurston, Dylan P.; Zickert, Christian K.*, [**The complex volume of \\(\mathrm{SL}(n,\mathbb{C})\\)-representations of 3-manifolds**](https://doi.org/10.1215/00127094-3121185), Duke Math. J. 164, No. 11, 2099-2160 (2015). [ZBL1335.57034](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1335.57034).

Comment: MathJax note: because escaping is fun, you can't use `\( \)` in MathJax, but instead `\\\\( \\\\)` (which is why we mostly use `$ $` ).  See my (wrongly titled) MMO post [Having the MO Mathjax parser recognise \\( \\) is a regex away](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/5662/having-the-mo-mathjax-parser-recognise-is-a-regex-away) (whose title I mis-escaped just now, ha!).  I edited accordingly.